# hashing to a fixed number of buckets using salt

Tags: hash, md5, salt

We currently generate hashes for user-ids in our system (using md5) and bucket them into range buckets (range is 0 to 100, buckets can be 0-30, 31-70, 71-100). This process works this way - we calculate hash for a user as an int value, take the first three digits and translate that to a percentage. This percentage decides the bucket for the user. This works fine for now and the percentages are random over the range. Now we also want the bucketing to factor in another key for the user (his city). If I add the city as a salt to the hash, will the hash generate random buckets at the city level. For e.g. for users in seattle, if we use the hashstring as `SEATTLE + user_id1`, `NEWYORK + user_id2` and calculate percentages in the same way as before. Will this lead to almost random percentages at the region level (all SEATTLE users are distributed randomly in buckets from 0-100)

Comment: Yes, it will. You can discover this by a simple experiment.

Comment: its not random for large datasets. My theory is that adding salt will still generate random numbers overall but it will not have any affect on the randomization at city level.